# How to Automate the application which is accesible through remote desktop

Tags: automation, remote-desktop

I have a requirement to automate one of my application which is accessible only through Remote desktop connection.

I normally connect to the application using following steps
1)  Navigate to remote desktop connection and enter Ip address
2)  Enter Server User id ,password
3)  Then open application using browser.

Please help with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your problems in 2steps :
1. Login to the box via java code (or any other preferable language, you are comfortable).

Remote Desktop Connection

JAVA

```
// creating credentials
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdkey /generic:"+ip+" /user:"+userName+" /pass:"+password );
p.destroy();

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mstsc /v: "+ip+" /f /console");

Thread.sleep(2*60*1000); // min sec millisec
// deleting credentials
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdkey /delete:"+ip);
p1.destroy();
```

2. Once you able to login to the box, it is as simple as launching the browser, opening the application and running your scripts(these scripts should be present on your remote desktop where you want to run your scripts). This is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @kumar did the solution worked for you? or you still facing issue?